# Setting up environmental Variables through Batch File exits unexpectedly

Tags: batch-file

I'm creating a batch file to setup up environmental variable's for JSHOP2. The code accepts two user inputs and compares them with an existing ClassPath variable, if it does not exists then it sets the environmental variables.
Here is my code:

```
@echo off
color 0a
echo ............................Welcome to path to shop............................ 
echo .... Make sure you provide exact paths with full file name when prompted.
echo .... Once given the path of the file make sure you don't change the location of the file in        your computer. 
set /p "antlrPath=Enter the path of the antlr.jar file in your computer: "
set /p "jshop2Path=Enter the path of the compiled JSHOP2 source file (SomeName.jar) in your  computer: "
set @specifiedPath= %antlrPath%;%jshop2Path%
echo %@specifiedPath% %CLASSPATH% ::code runs fine upto this line then cmd exits unexpectedly
if %@specifiedPath% == %CLASSPATH% 
goto isAlreadySet
goto isNotAlreadySet
:isAlreadySet
echo yesss!
:isNotAlreadySet
echo no
pause
```

What is the problem?

Edit: code updated as asked by aphoria.

```
@echo off
color 0a
echo ............................Welcome to path to shop............................ 
echo .... Make sure you provide exact paths with full file name when prompted.
echo .... Once given the path of the file make sure you don't change the location of the file in    your computer.
set /p "antlrPath=Enter the path of the antlr.jar file in your computer: "
set /p "jshop2Path=Enter the path of the compiled JSHOP2 source file (SomeName.jar) in your  computer: " 
set @specifiedPath= %antlrPath%;%jshop2Path%
echo %@specifiedPath% %CLASSPATH%
if "%@specifiedPath%" == "%CLASSPATH%" (
goto isAlreadySet
) ELSE (
goto isNotAlreadySet
)
:isAlreadySet
echo yesss!
:isNotAlreadySet
echo no
pause
```

Comment: Start by removing the space after the equals in the line `set @specifiedPath= %antlrPath%;%jshop2Path%`. It should be `@specifiedPath=%antlrPath%;%jshop2Path%` without the space.

Comment: Thanks Ken your suggestion did it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IF` statement must all be on the same line or use parentheses across multiple lines.

**UPDATE**

- Added quotes to handle spaces in the paths.
- Added `/I` option to the `IF` statement for case insensitivity.

You could do this:

```
if /I "%@specifiedPath%" == "%CLASSPATH%" goto isAlreadySet
goto isNotAlreadySet
```

Or this:

```
if /I "%@specifiedPath%" == "%CLASSPATH%" (
  goto isAlreadySet
) ELSE (
  goto isNotAlreadySet
)
```

Comment: It did nothing :/
still same problem... It crashes the moment i hit enter after entering second path.

Comment: Are you running this by double-clicking or from a command prompt? Open a command prompt and run it so you can see what the error message is.

Comment: I've created a process.bat file and i'm editing it. I run it by double clicking it.

Comment: Open a command prompt and run your process.bat file. The window will stay open so you can see the error message.

Comment: O yeah.. it says [my input text] was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Something is still broken with your `IF` statement. Update your code in the question to what it looks like now.

Comment: See my update to my answer. You probably have spaces in your paths, so you need quotes around the variables.

Comment: updated the code in my question. The error is removed but the code is always redirecting to no path.. I've tried giving same values but its only goto No

Comment: See update. Add `/I` to the `IF` for case-insensitive string comparison.

Comment: Thanks alot dear. I don't have enough reputation to vote up otherwise you deserve it :)

Comment: How can i check or logical operator in if statement i mean if (statement) or (statement) goto :ok

how its possible?

Comment: You can't in batch. You will need to use two `IF` statements. `IF yourcomparison GOTO :ok` followed by `IF yourothercomparison GOTO :ok`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for your support. My problem is finally solved. For all those who get this problem here is my final code.

```
@echo off
color 0a
echo ............................Welcome to path to shop............................ 
echo .... Make sure you provide exact paths with full file name when prompted.
echo .... Once given the path of the file make sure you don't change the location of the file in your computer.
set /p "antlrPath=Enter the path of the antlr.jar file in your computer: "
set /p "jshop2Path=Enter the path of the compiled JSHOP2 source file (SomeName.jar) in your computer: "
set @specifiedPath=%antlrPath%;%jshop2Path%
echo %@specifiedPath% %CLASSPATH%
if "%@specifiedPath%" == "%CLASSPATH%" (
goto isAlreadySet
) ELSE (
goto isNotAlreadySet
)
:isAlreadySet
echo yesss!
goto end
:isNotAlreadySet
echo no
:end
pause
```

Thanks Again :)